# Touhou Song Identification Request?

Tags: music, touhou-project

someone knows the exactly name of the song that is hearing in this video? The creator says that is a remix from Touhou called Eletric Cat but I can't find any song related, hope its okay.

Here's the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nERXaTVy9fU

Yesterday, one person told me that he doesnt know the song name but he's sure that is an arrange from Chen's Theme, So based in this, someone knows who could be the Circle/Artist made this?.

Comment: do you want the original song (without remix) or not ?

Answer (score 2):

According to video OP, it's from this album:
http://touhourecords.blogspot.fr/2016/03/kyandoru-raito-no-konran-emotional.html

- Title: Electric cat
- Album: Emotional Catastrophic Wind
- Circle: Kyandoru Raito no Konran

I think I'll go against Gagantuous and saying that the original is not `Withered Leaf` but `Fantastic Tales from Tohno` (遠野幻想物語):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09FE5mEg-Mg

Comment: I didnt mention the "electric cat" part in the question.. sorry

Answer (score 0):

From The wiki, The name of this ost sure is from Stage 2 Boss - Chen's theme

`Diao Ye Zong (withered leaf)` or `ティアオイエツォン(withered leaf)`

[Chen's Theme Song Explanation Wiki](https://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Perfect_Cherry_Blossom/Music#Stage_2_theme)

> I composed this title with the image of an energetic youkai girl in
>   mind. This song is based purely on improvisation, because I found that
>   if I think too much while composing the music tends to end up strange.
>   Well, with the help of more than a little booze... All in all, this is
>   an honest song (^^;

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-W4pzWVS5wk